# Splitting a record in Multiple Record in PIG

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-pig

I want to create multiple input for the last three fields.From a single record i want to create a single instance of of tax per record? What method i should use in Pig ?

input schema

```
id     key   adr          name      tax     tax1     tax2

123456|1234|123 main st| jane doe| 123xxx | 124xxx | 125xxx
```

Is it possible in Pig to get the following output from the above input?

```
123456|1234|123 main st| jane doe| 123xxx 

123456|1234|123 main st| jane doe| 124xxx 

123456|1234|123 main st| jane doe| 125xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ToBag()

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,FLATTEN(ToBag($4,$5,$6));
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that. But instead of Giving me separate record for each instance of tax. It creates a Bag of tax .

Comment: try FLATTEN(TOBAG($4,$5,$6))